# Adding null partition value to the glue table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Iam pretty new to glue here so will try to phrase my question in very lame manner.Assume I have My data partitioned by a column in s3. Say my folder looks something like this

```
s3://bucket/key/state=state1
s3://bucket/key/state=state2
s3://bucket/key/state=null
```

Now assume that I have to actually add partition to glue column based on state here. Iam using [Amazon's glue API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-PartitionInput) to add partition
while adding the partition, I see null is getting converted to 'null'(String formatted). Is there a way where i don't format the same as String null while Iam passing the add partition to the glue API

Comment: So you want that the partition name for null values is not null but a different string, did I understand that correct?

Comment: No. I would want the data to be null rather than 'null'

Comment: So that there is no partition null but rather no data when state is null?

Comment: Yeah. Thats right

Comment: Then why don't you just filter all records where state is null? Could you provide your code?